# View setView Odd Behavior

Tags: android, android-layout, alpha

I have been working and Googling for a while and I seem to be stumped. This is the view for my fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

  <include layout="@layout/swipe_hint"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
  ... other views
</RelativeLayout>
```

The layout swipe_hint looks like so:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/swipe_hint_layout"
              android:visibility="gone"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  ... more views
```

Now in Java code I am trying to change the alpha independently like so:

```
// this fragment's view is the first xml layout above
View pageOneLayout = fragment.getView();
// get the layout of the swipe hint through the fragment's view since it is included
View swipeView = pageOneLayout.findViewById(R.id.swipe_hint_layout);

// here is where I run into problems
pageOneLayout.setAlpha(.25f);
swipeView.setAlpha(1);
```

Setting `pageOneLayout` alpha to .25 changes the alpha of the whole layout to 25% transparent which is to be expected. However when setting the alpha for `swipeView` separately it seems to have no effect. The `swipeView` is still .25 transparent. I would think setting the alpha separately like this would result in the two views having separate levels of transparency. However this is not the case. Can anyone out there shed some light on the subject??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of this behaviour is that every child in RelativeLayout and LinearLayout inherits alpha from its parent.

If you want to have separate alpha levels try using FrameLayout.

Comment: but wouldn't setting the child's alpha break that inheritance?

Comment: Try setting 0.5 to child and see what happens.

Comment: is there a way to break the inheritance so i can have these at 2 different alpha levels?